# Unable to run SAS script through C#

Tags: c#, sas

I have A requirement to run SAS script through Web application using asp.net and c#.

I have used ProcessStartInfo to execute SAS script. This works fine locally with solution.Once i hosted the application in IIS, it is not working and returning exit code with 111. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("path of SAS EXE","file path");
int exitCode = 0;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(info);
p.WaitForExit();
exitCode = p.ExitCode;
```

Comment: Does script use any environmental variables?  The environment variables are not setup when using process.

Comment: No, its not using any environment variable.

Comment: IIS the uses have GUEST privileges and have no access to the IIS file system.  All read/writes to files should be done on a network drive from client where users have more access.  You can run the c# application on IIS with RUN AS ADMIN but this is not recommended.

Comment: I am using administrator account only, still not able to run the application.

Comment: There may be an app missing on IIS.  Check Event Viewer to see if there are any Errors occurring.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I checked it, no errors are there. I think this SAS.exe is opening. Is there any help, how to start the sas.exe

Comment: You need to reference full path of the executable because the environmental variable PATH is not defined (and any objects that are referenced need full path).  See http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p16esisc4nrd5sn1ps5l6u8f79k6.htm

Comment: I have given Full paths only, this is running locally. I hosted in application in IIS then this peace of code returns 111 code and not running SAS file. Find the below code: ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("D:\\SAS\\SASFoundation\\9.3\\sas.exe", "D:\\OOPCSimulator\\OOPC2019PlanFinder\\programs\\OOPCV1P.sas");
int exitCode = 0;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(info);
p.WaitForExit();
exitCode = p.ExitCode;

Comment: Can you create a bat file with same and does it run?  I wouldn't use D drive.  Remember this is running on client and client may not have d: drive mapped.  You should be able to just use two backslashes without the drive letter.  If you use the drive letter than you only need one backslash.

Comment: I have create Bat file, Console Application and web service and even though dll. Nothing is working for me. I am assuming some settings need to be done in IIS. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Issue is probably you are trying to read/write on the IIS and users do not have privilege or an application (like Microsoft Office not installed) is cause issue.  I would check the Event Viewer on IIS to see if any errors are occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have checked the event Viewer and corrected the error. It was problem with SAS User, i have done some changes in SAS config file. It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered not doing it using process? SAS has a technology called Integration Technologies which you most likely have. It interfaces using a COM interface. You can then execute SAS that way and pass what is needed vs using a command line call.

Here is sample code:

```
SAS.Workspace ws = new Workspace();
LanguageService ls = ws.LanguageService;
StoredProcessService sp = ls.StoredProcessService;
sp.Repository = @"file:" + @"x:\temp";
sp.Execute("test.sas", string.Empty);
string log = ls.FlushLog(1000);
```

If you need to do it via the process start, here is code:

Also, if you are passing commands to SAS, I don't see any. You have to pass commands to SAS from command line (program name at a minimum). info.Arguments is a start. Also, redirect the std output to a file. Look at info.RedirectStandardOutput and info.RedirectStandardError. However, i don't believe that is the issue. I think you are encountering a security issue. Look at Event Viewer and see if it pops up. IISS requires security to execute in a directory.

Finally, why are you using IIS? Unless you have a legacy requirement, IIS should not be used. Switch to Kestrel and ASP.NET Core. I will be presenting a paper at SGF on the use of SAS in this way. Download the paper and code as soon as they are available (next week?)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Where can i find the dll for SAS.Workspace.  My application in asp.net 4.5 and hosted in IIS. As per the new requirement i am adding one more page to the existing application. And one more thing is i have to run the SAS script remotely not in the same Machine.